# Limit the size of an UIImage which is set programmatically

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios5

I'm dynamically loading images from a web service. The images will be loaded (with `[UIImage imageWithData:data];`) and be placed in a in an `UIImageView` in my custom `UITableViewCell` using the `setImage` message

. I gave the imageView a width and height of 27 by 19 in the interface builder and told him to "Aspect fit" (tried all the others too btw), but the image doesn't do that. It just scales (in aspect, I think) to fill the view cell.

I tried a lot of things, like resizing the image (does the job, but I can count the pixels on my retina display), resizing the UIImageView... But I just don't get is... Someone got an idea what I'm doing wrong?

The code that changes the cell:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *MyIdentifier = @"MyIdentifier";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"NewsTableViewCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = self.tableCell;
        self.tableCell = nil;
    }

    viArticle *article = [self.viData.articles objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    UILabel *label;

    label = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:1];
    label.text = article.title;

    label = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:2];
    label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", article.time, article.type];

    if (article.image != nil) {
        UIImageView *imageView;
        imageView = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:0];
        [imageView setImage:article.image];

    }

    return cell;
}
```

This is the view:

[image: Custom tableView cell]

And the settings:

[image]

Comment: Your problem here is unclear. You have instructed it to use "Aspect fit", and the image is being scaled to fill the view... That is exactly what you are asking it to do. Perhaps you are targeting the wrong view?

Comment: It should "Aspect fit" inside of the `UIImageView`, but it does outside of it.. And I don't know why. If I add an image in IB it shows correctly.

Comment: We need to see the code you're using I think.

Comment: I just edited my question. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just posted a "solution" earlier today, but that seem to work, but was a wrong assumption. After asking on IRC I found the *real* solution. I was using the `tag` 0, that one shouldn't be used. Changing it to an higher value really solved my problem. Sometimes it can be thát easy. :)

Thanks y'all.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to resize the `UIImageView` you can use the frame property.

suppose you have a `UIImageView` declare in .h file(lets take `UIImageView *myImage;`) and it is linked to the interface builder too.
you have synthesis it in .m class etc.

then when you want to resize the UIImageView, use

```
myImage.frame = CGRect(x,y,width,height);
```

Note: by declaring the width and height in the code, the width and height declared in the IB will be override.

then dont forget to add it to subview,

```
i.e [self.view addSubview:myImage];
```

and its done, you can see the changes.

Comment: That's one of the things I tried, it just doesn't seem to change anything. But why should I add it to subview? It's built in IB, so it's already there?

Comment: As you are defining a new frame to it you have it to subview.

Comment: @GuidoH you can try it because it worked for me. and if it worked for you too then mark it  as answer pls.

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you untick "Autoresize Subviews"?

Comment: Doesn't change anything. Tried it when I saw the picture over here.

Answer (score 0):

@GuidoH hey sorry for the late reply.. 
Here is the code that will add the image to the table view cell.

```
-(UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
       static NSString *SimpleTableIdentifier = @" SimpleTableIdentifier ";
       UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:   SimpleTableIdentifier];
       if (cell == nil) 
       { 
          cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc]
          initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:SimpleTableIdentifier] autorelease];
       }

      UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"star.png"]; 
      cell.imageView.image = image;
      NSUInteger row = [indexPath row]; 
      cell.textLabel.text = [listData objectAtIndex:row];
      return cell;
}

//use this delegate it will increase the row size and thus your imagesize will get increased too.

-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
        return 80;   //value can be changed
}
```

I would suggest scaling the images will surely lead to slow performance by your app.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But that's not really solving my problem. I'm able to add the image to the cell, but it's not showing in the right size. I'm getting the image from an URL, which returns the image. But when I add it to the image view, it doesn't show correctly, even if I resize the image server side to the correct size. I guess that the problem might be in the fact that I'm using it on a retina display and the IB doesn't use that sizes.